# Optimizing adding zero padding in a number

Tags: java

I'm practicing on how to optimize codes so any suggestion would be much appreciated. I have this method that adds zero padding to a number when its being incremented. The code are as follows:

```
public class CommonAlgorithm {

    NumberRetrieve retrieve;

    public long incrementNumber(CommonNumber t) {
        CommonNumberFacade facade = new CommonNumberFacade(retrieve.apply(t));
        String number = facade.getGeneratedNumber();

        Long num = Long.parseLong(number);
        num++;

        String result = "";
        if (String.valueOf(num).length() < number.length()) {
            int length = number.length() - String.valueOf(num).length();
            String zero = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                zero += "0";
            }

            result = zero + num;
        } else {
            result = String.valueOf(num);
        }

        return Long.parseLong(t.getPrefix()+result);
    }
}
```

Are there more ways to optimize the code above?

Just in case anyone asks for the purpose of the function, the premise goes like this:

The function returns a number that is composed of the following: a 'prefix' and a 'number'. These two are concatenated to each other after the number has been incremented by 1. However, I realized that if the value of the `number` has zero padding in it, those zeroes will be disappear once they are converted into a `long` data type. Therefore if the following values are applied:

prefix = 123
number = 000001

The return value will be `1232` instead of `123000002`. That is the problem that the function above is solving. I can't change the return type of the `facade.generatedNumber()` function into `long` as I need to return that `String` return type somewhere in my project eventually. I hope you could give a couple of suggestions

Comment: **Maybe** this question would be a better fit over at [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How about something like `prefix * Math.pow(10, number.length() + num` ?

Comment: `numStr = String.valueOf(num); result = prefix + number.substring(0, number.length()-numStr.length()) + numStr;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your if-else statement as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBulder();
String numStr = String.valueOf(num);
for (int i = numStr.length(); i < number.length(); i++) {
    sb.append('0');
}
sb.append(numStr);
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

A few simple things:

- You use String objects to *build* your results, like `zero` and `result`. Those could be StringBuilder objects. That would clearly express your intent to **build** strings!
- You could look into using [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))
- You are invoking `String.valueOf(num);` three times, for the same *num*. You could do that once initially, and reuse that value, instead of computing it repeatedly.

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot about that StringBuilder. Thanks for pointing that out. And also with the `String.valueOf(num)`. I always thought fewer lines meant better code but what you said was more efficient

Comment: @Uzi Yes, fewer lines are better than more lines. But you still want to minimize code **duplication**. This is not only about performance, it is also about the fact that you would potentially have to change three instances of code, instead of a single place!

Answer (score 2):

Use the numerical primitive type `long` instead of the Object wrapper `Long`.

```
    long num = Long.parseLong(number);
    num++;
```

Place the string representation of `num` in its own variable.

```
    String numStr = String.valueOf(num);
```

Zero padding to keep the number of original digits is only needed for increments for **negative** numbers, and then only for carries / digits '0'. This means that the zeroes should go *after* the sign.

`String +, +=` is costly, use a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number.length());
```

Optimal is a relative, it would be okay to do:

```
    long num = Long.parseLong(number);
    ++num;

    String paddedNumStr = numStr.length >= number.length() ? numStr
                    : String.format("%" + number.length() + "d", num);
```

Using an if-expression as heuristic optimisation for 95% of the cases.

Comment: *if-expression* -> *ternary operator*

Comment: @Lino yes good point, I simplified, as "ternary operator" needs clarification, but should have been mentioned. It means operator with _three_ operands, and the only ternary operators are `~?~:~` and possibly `~[~]=~` (+=, -=, ...). In general with "ternary operator" `?:` is meant, but it is actually a variation on _unary_ and _binary_ operator.

Comment: woah. I'm not familiar yet with ternary operators. I guess I'll have to look it up but it looks way better than what I originally did. Also, I never really understood the difference between += and using StringBuilder.

Comment: @Uzi `condition ? thenvalue : elsevalue`; reading `IF condition THEN thenvalue ELSE elsevalue`. Also called _conditional expression_ (as opposed to the _conditional statement_ if-else).

Comment: @JoopEggen are they only used for conditions with two possible outcomes or can the condition continue as we like?

Comment: `int sign = n < 0 ? -1 : n == 0 ? 0 : 1;` for instance, just like if-else-if-else`